# Как выгрузить данные из df в CSV файл с сохранением имени индексов и столбцов?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Задание имен индексов и столбцов производится следующим образом:

```
df.index.names = ['First','Second']    #мультииндекс
df.columns.names = ['Param']
```

При последующей выгрузке в .csv этого DataFrame

```
df.to_csv(r'C:\folder')
```

В .csv файл не попадают имена индексов, указанные выше

Вывод df выглядит следующим образом:

```
Out[1]:
    Param               2020-01-01 2020-01-08  ... 2020-03-11 2020-03-18
    First     Second                           ...                      
    SR0013863 GFC007286       0.33        0.4  ...       0.43       0.04
    SR0016151 GFC006849       0.49       0.66  ...       0.57          0
              GFC007286        0.1       0.12  ...       0.08       0.01

    [3 rows x 12 columns]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы в .csv файл попали имена строк и столбцов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию, метод [DataFrame.to_csv(filename)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) сохраняет имена столбцов мультииндекса.

Пример:

```
In [11]: df = (pd
               .DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,3)), 
                         columns=["idx1", "idx2", "val"])
               .set_index(["idx1","idx2"]))

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
           val
idx1 idx2
8    0       6
3    0       4
6    4       8
     2       4
7    1       5

In [13]: df.to_csv(r"c:\temp\test.csv")
```

Результат:

```
idx1,idx2,val
8,0,6
3,0,4
6,4,8
6,2,4
7,1,5
```

чтобы прочитать такой CSV файл и получить мультииндекс:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=[0,1])
```

или указав имена столбцов мультииндекса:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=["idx1","idx2"])
```

---

Если в старых версиях Pandas, `df.to_csv()` не сохраняет имена столбцов мультииндекса, то проще всего превратить их в обычные столбцы перед выгрузкой DF в CSV:

```
df.reset_index().to_csv(filename, index=False)
```